# Может ли быть более одного рута в *nix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, root, sudo

Может ли быть более одного рута в *nix?

Comment: рута или пользователя с правами рута?

Comment: какая разница ?

Comment: @Ask большая...

Comment: Про другие юниксы не в курсе, но как минимум в Linux во многих местах захардкожена проверка на GLOBAL_ROOT_UID, так что и рут ровно один

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конкретный ответ зависит от того, что именно значит «рут» и что значит «более одного»:

- Если «рут» — это пользователь с *именем* (*user name*) `root`, то такой в системе может быть только один. т.к. имена пользователей уникальны.
- Если «рут» — это пользователь с *идентификатором*, (*User ID*, *UID*) равным `0` (и с соответствующими правами), то ему могут соответствовать несколько разных *имён* и, как следствие, паролей, домашних каталогов и логин-оболочек. Считать ли в таком случае, что это несколько «разных рутов» или «один с несколькими именами» — вопрос интерпретации и философских взглядов.

  ИМХО первый вариант несколько попахивает шизофренией, так что я бы говорил, что `root` в таком случае всё равно один.

Так например, в BSD-системах традиционно у пользователя с *UID*=`0` есть второе имя `toor`.

Comment: Ну и дополнить объяснением разницы между UID и effective UID для полноты картины.

Comment: @0andriy, я б не против, но к вопросу это не имеет отношения...

Comment: Почему же? Кто-то вон поставил метку `sudo`.

Comment: @0andriy, к EUID'у это всё равно чуть больше, чем никакое отношение имеет...